# How to divide dataframe into 2 equal parts (first half rows and second half rows) - in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` and need to break it into 2 equal `dataframes`.

*1st dataframe* **would contain top half rows and 2nd would contain the remaining rows**.

Please help how to achieve this using `python`.

Also in both the even rows scenario and odd rows scenario (as in odd rows I would need to drop the last row to make it equal).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample data input with expected output for both cases.

Comment: suppose if I have the following ```DataFrame```
```
lst = ["Geeks","For", "Geeks", "is",  
            "portal", "for", "Geeks","Vinay"] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(lst) 
print(df) 
```
I can take it's equal upper half by using ```head()``` command like follow

```
df.head(len(df)//2)
```
And below half can be accessed by using ```tail()``` command

```
df.tail(len(df)//2)
```

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have added the sample data and expected outcomes for both cases. Notice in odd rows case, the last row has been excluded..

Comment: @Kay Check my comment I think it will help you.

Comment: @VinayKumarShukla it doesn't account for the odd number of rows case.

Comment: @Kay Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `df`:

```
In [122]: df
Out[122]: 
    id  days  sold  days_lag
0    1     1     1         0
1    1     3     0         2
2    1     3     1         2
3    1     8     1         5
4    1     8     1         5
5    1     8     0         5
6    2     3     0         0
7    2     8     1         5
8    2     8     1         5
9    2     9     2         1
10   2     9     0         1
11   2    12     1         3
12   3     4     5         6
```

Use [`numpy.array_split()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
In [127]: import numpy as np

In [128]: def split_df(df):
     ...:     if len(df) % 2 != 0:  # Handling `df` with `odd` number of rows
     ...:         df = df.iloc[:-1, :]
     ...:     df1, df2 =  np.array_split(df, 2)
     ...:     return df1, df2
     ...: 

In [130]: df1, df2 = split_df(df)

In [131]: df1
Out[131]: 
   id  days  sold  days_lag
0   1     1     1         0
1   1     3     0         2
2   1     3     1         2
3   1     8     1         5
4   1     8     1         5
5   1     8     0         5

In [133]: df2
Out[133]: 
    id  days  sold  days_lag
6    2     3     0         0
7    2     8     1         5
8    2     8     1         5
9    2     9     2         1
10   2     9     0         1
11   2    12     1         3
```

Answer (score 1):

with a simple eg. you can try as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13],['Tom',20],['Jerry',25]]
#data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13],['Tom',20]]
data1 = data[0:int(len(data)/2)]
if (len(data) % 2) == 0:
    data2 = data[int(len(data)/2):]
else:
    data2 = data[int(len(data)/2):-1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 'Age'], dtype=float); print("1st half:\n",df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name', 'Age'], dtype=float); print("2nd Half:\n",df2)
```

Output:

D:\Python>python temp.py

```
1st half:
    Name   Age
 0  Alex  10.0
 1   Bob  12.0
2nd Half:
    Name   Age
 0  Clarke  13.0
 1     Tom  20.0
```